# Import in js file becomes 'myProperty' is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Why do I get this error that the variable is defined but not used when doing a import? They are in the same folder. I am using it. Thanks for input!

**error**

> 'componentName' is defined but never used.

**dynamic-component-data-mapping.js**

```
import { componentName } from './strapi-helpers.js'

function mapData(response, componentName) {
  const componentList = response.reduce(function(matchedComponents, component) {
    if (component.__component === componentName) {
      component.__component = componentName(component.__component)

      matchedComponents.push(component)
    }

    return matchedComponents
  }, [])

  return componentList
}

export {
  mapData
}
```

**strapi-helpers.js**

```
function componentName(currentName) {
  if (currentName && currentName.indexOf('.')) {
    return currentName.replace('.', '-')
  }
}

export {
  componentName
}
```

Comment: your function shadows the import, with a parameter of the same name. It is therefore never used.

Comment: Perhaps because there's nothing calling the `mapData()` function in that file? The `componentName` parameter is just that. It's not related to the import until something calls it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function shadows the import, with a parameter of the same name. It is therefore never used.